# Queue or deny too many concurrent http requests

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

When I check my error logs, I see many requests like this - up to 100 requests coming from a single ip:

```
[Mon Oct 21 21:20:05 2013] [error] [client 198.204.250.82] File does not exist: /var/www/html/websql
[Mon Oct 21 21:20:06 2013] [error] [client 198.204.250.82] File does not exist: /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin
[Mon Oct 21 21:20:06 2013] [error] [client 198.204.250.82] File does not exist: /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
[Mon Oct 21 21:20:06 2013] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
```

I'd like to be able to restrict the number of connections per ip to 4 so hack attempts like these do not max out my MaxClients. Ideally, any concurrent requests above the 4 get queued up and addressed after the open connections have timed out. If that's not possible, then denying concurrent requests above 4 is also a possibility.

I'm running apache on EC2. Anyone know of a relatively easy way of doing this?

Comment: This is not a question for [so]. It might be a good fit for [webmasters.se]